# jQuery-populated <select> option values don't submit

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select class="fiLocations"></select>` dropdown that I'm populating from an array, like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var fiLocations=["One", "Two", "Three"];

for (i=0;i<fiLocations.length;i++){
   $('<option/>').val(fiLocations[i]).html(fiLocations[i]).appendTo('.fiLocations');
}

}
```

The values of the selected option are not being submitted! Hardcoded options do submit.
I presume I need to inform the browser of the changes made... How do I do that?

Comment: can you show some html? and maybe a fiddle?

Comment: are you appending then selecting on the screen then submitting?

Comment: The posted code works fine for me.  You're seeing the options in the dropdown, just not getting the value on the backend?

Comment: yes he is saying that he cannot get the values to submit

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DnzzQ/

Comment: @0x90: How would livequery help (and isn't part of jQuery as `.live()`)?

Comment: the `value` is populated correctly, but not passed on. It's an AJAX form, does that affect matters? I'm using the "Contact Form 7" WordPress plugin.

Comment: look at my comment on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fiLocations=["One", "Two", "Three"];

for (i=0;i<fiLocations.length;i++){
   var option = "<option SELECTED='SELECTED' value='"+fiLocations[i]+"'>"+fiLocations[i]+"</option>";
        $('.fiLocations').append(option);
}
```

My edit to the code adds the selected attribute when creating the options. Now you need to add also the selector a attribute of

```
<select multiple="multiple">
```

so all of the options can be selected. Now however if you want them to not be selected until you call the ajax, remove the `selected='selected'` part in the creation code function and then use

```
$('.fiLocations option').attr('selected','selected');
```

before you call the ajax function.

Comment: While the `value` is populated, this doesn't fix my problem :(

Comment: before your ajax option sends you must have all the options selected by      $('.fiLocations option').attr('selected','selected'); in order for the values to be passed or if you want them selected as you add them then add a "<option selected='selected' value='"

Comment: I imagine that will fix it, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Where do I put `$('.fiLocations option').attr('selected','selected');`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: depends if you want them selected as you add them or before you submit them

Comment: I would like the one selected last by the user to be submitted.

Comment: ok now that makes the problem less clear. I am not understanding how the user is selecting the option. Could you elaborate your question to include the ajax function, html, and the logical flow of the use of the page. thanks

Comment: By "selecting the option" I just mean whatever option the user chooses from the dropdown menu.

Comment: well then the selected value should be passed correctly to your ajax function if you are using it correctly. If you are not getting the selected value tehn you might want to show your ajax function in the question

Answer (score 0):

In your example when you call the `.val()` part, it doesn't actually populate the non-existent value attribute of the `<option>` tag. Because of that I think the options you're creating aren't submitting values.

Try doing it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fiLocations=["One", "Two", "Three"];

    for (i=0;i<fiLocations.length;i++){
        $('<option/>').attr("value",fiLocations[i]).text(fiLocations[i]).appendTo('.fiLocations');
    }
}
```

Comment: umm almost exactly what i proposed